# Cannot validate the signature with X509Certificate2

Tags: c#, .net, cryptography, x509certificate2

I am trying to use a self signed certificate to sign a string and then verify that the string is signed correctly.

This is how I create my self signed certificate:

```
makecert -r -n "CN=AuthCert2" -ss my -a sha1 -pe
```

After this I export the certificate to a pfx file and try to run the following code:

```
using System;
using System.Text;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting;
using System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates;
using System.Security.Cryptography;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Security;

[TestClass]
public class TestSign
{

        [TestMethod]
        public void TestSignAndVerify()
        {
            string toSignString = "This is my string to sign";

            byte[] data = UnicodeEncoding.UTF8.GetBytes(toSignString);

            SHA1Managed sha1 = new SHA1Managed();
            byte[] hash = sha1.ComputeHash(data);

            X509Certificate2 signCert = new X509Certificate2("authcert2.pfx", "authpass");
            var csp = (RSACryptoServiceProvider)signCert.PrivateKey;

            byte[] signedData = csp.SignData(hash, CryptoConfig.MapNameToOID("SHA1"));

            RSACryptoServiceProvider csp2 = (RSACryptoServiceProvider)signCert.PublicKey.Key;

            bool result = csp2.VerifyHash(hash, CryptoConfig.MapNameToOID("SHA1"), signedData);
        }
}
```

Yet I am always getting result as false. I am sure I am missing something very basic here. Any idea what is going on or how I can debug the problem?

thanks,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two things wrong within the code. First of all, the `SignData` computation already includes calculating the hash (no need to do it yourself) and the second is that you are using `VerifyHash` instead of `VerifyData`.